# Understanding dependency inversion

Tags: layers

According to the definition by Robert Martin, high level modules should not depend on low level modules, instead both should depend on abstractions.

So if I have a domain entity `Invoice` that uses an interface `InvoiceRepository` for persistence, and an infrastructure layer where this interface is implemented in a class `PdoInvoiceRepository`, then both modules - the entity and the persistence mechanism - depend on the abstraction (interface)?

Further, if the methods in above interface do not depend on the implementation details but instead express the abstracted needs of my domain model, then I have achieved dependency inversion?

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind dependency inversion is to **prevent hard-coded dependencies within a class.**

If I write this:

```
public class Customer
{
    private CustomerRepository _repository;
    
    public Customer()
    {
        _repository = new CustomerRepository();
    }
}
```

Then I have tightly bound `CustomerRepository` to `Customer`.

But if, instead, I write

```
public class Customer
{
    private ICustomerRepository _repository

    public Customer(ICustomerRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

I can then write:

```
var customer = new Customer(new RepositoryClassThatImplementsICustomerRepository());
```

So you can hand the constructor of my class any object that implements the `ICustomerRepository` interface.  The class is no longer tightly-coupled to a specific implementation of Customer Repository.

`ICustomerRepository` is an *abstraction;* it defines the operations that are valid for a repository object that satisfies `Customer`'s requirements.

Comment: So far, so clear. What about the second part of the definition which states that abstractions should not depend on details. My interpretation is that the interface methods should express what my higher level module needs, so the class that implements said interface should be modeled to fit the abstraction.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/64932/1204